# What avail Mem means for AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I created a free-tier AWS EC2 instance (ubuntu linux)
After installing several softwares, I want to check the memory usage status of this instance. I connect this instance through SSH, and input command `top`, then I get the result as
[image]

As I know MiB Swap indicate the virtual memory. In my case, the size of virtual memory is 0, but what does `608.2 avail Mem` mean here?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not linux or server administration issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: The `top` output is arguably just poorly presented IMHO. It's not related to the swap as it implies - notice the `.` after the `used` before that. That value is the amount of available processor memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man pages under 2c. MEMORY usage,

The available memory shown in line 2 represents the estimated physical memory available for starting new applications before a swap is needed.

To find this information yourself and learn more about the information presentation, run the command:
"man top" 
Next type "/MEMORY Usage" and  and type "n" several times until you arrive at section 2c.  This was done using the RHEL8 man pages but should be similar on other systems.